# Using a <form> in an options page & browser.storage.local.get() does not work in content script

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am working on a Firefox Add-on where a user can set some values on the options page. When the users visits sites, the content script gets executed which then needs to read the values set previously on the options page.

I followed every step underneath the 'Adding settings' headline of the MDN guide "[Implement a settings page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Implement_a_settings_page)" and created all the files with the given example code. While setting, changing and reading the values on the options page is working fine, I can not do the same in the content script file (named borderify.js in the guide). In the concrete code example of the guide it always uses the default blue border, no matter what is set on the options page.

I checked the wiki page of the content scripts but there it just says: 'In addition to the standard DOM APIs, content scripts can use the following WebExtension APIs: [...] Everything from storage.'

All this was tested with a complete new Firefox profile and version 50.0.2.

Can somebody please help me with this issue?

manifest.json

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Settings example",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["borderify.js"]
    }
  ],

  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "settings-example@mozilla.org"
    }
  },

  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html"
  },

  "permissions": ["storage"]

}
```

options.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>

  <body>

    <form>
    <label>Border color<input type="text" id="color" ></label>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>

    <script src="options.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

options.js

```
function saveOptions(e) {
  browser.storage.local.set({
    color: document.querySelector("#color").value
  });
}

function restoreOptions() {

  function setCurrentChoice(result) {
    document.querySelector("#color").value = result.color || "blue";
  }

  function onError(error) {
    console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
  }

  var getting = browser.storage.local.get("color");
  getting.then(setCurrentChoice, onError);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", restoreOptions);
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", saveOptions);
```

borderify.js

```
function onError(error) {
  console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
}

function onGot(item) {
  var color = "blue";
  if (item.color) {
    color = item.color;
  }
  document.body.style.border = "10px solid " + color;
}

var getting = browser.storage.local.get("color");
getting.then(onGot, onError);
```

Comment: Note: Saying "latest version" of Firefox does not help us. Please be specific, if for no other reason than this question will exist for years, so even if we assume you mean the Firefox main release version, people won't know what version you mean years from now. In addition, Firefox always has many versions, including, but not limited to: [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/), Firefox Nightly, Firefox Beta, Firefox Unbranded Beta, Firefox Unbranded Release, and what most people use: Firefox (standard release).

Comment: Sorry, the version is 50.0.2. I will also add the code for the example files to the question.

Comment: What, *exactly*, was shown in the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (Ctrl-Shift-J, or Cmd-Shift-J on OSX) when you tried to install and use the extension?

Comment: Did you reload the web page after changing the options?

Comment: I reloaded the tested sites and opened new ones too but they all showed the blue border although I changed the value to red in the settings page and clicked on save. The console does not output anything addon related, however when I add console.log(item.color); at the beginning of the onGot function in borderify.js in outputs undefined in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues which are preventing this code from working:

1. A bug in Firefox versions prior to 52 which results in an Array of Objects being returned when the Promise from `browser.storage.local.get()` is fulfilled in a content script. This Promise is supposed to be fulfilled with an Object.
2. Using the `submit` event of a `<form>` in an options page without executing `preventDefault()` in your event handler.

### Firefox bug in [`browser.storage.local.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/get) for Firefox versions < 52

In your content script, when the Promise from `browser.storage.local.get()` fulfills you receive an Array of one Objects instead of an Object. The Object in the array correctly has the `color` property. If you use the same code with `browser.storage.local.get()` in your *options.js* you correctly get an Object. In Firefox Developer Edition (52.0a2) and Nightly (53.0a1), an Object is correctly received.

Using the **`chrome.storage.local.get()`** API correctly returns an Object in all situations. I would recommend using this API instead of `browser.storage.local.get()`.

If you decide to continue to use `browser.storage.local.get()`, then you will need to account for currently getting an Array of Objects (with the correct Object in `item[0]`) in Firefox < 52 and correctly getting an Object in Firefox >= 52.

### Using the `submit` event of a `<form>` in an options page requires `preventDefault()`

This is an issue in the code which was on the MDN page "[Implement a settings page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Implement_a_settings_page)". I have updated the code on that page to reflect the issue described below.

The problem is that you are using the `submit` event of a `<form>` in your *options.html* and *options.js* without preventing the default action with [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

If you do not prevent the default action, Firefox attempts to submit the page to the originating URL. On an Options page, this, obviously, fails. However, it fails in a way that causes Firefox to reload the options page. This destroys the scope in which your options page previously existed causing the call to `storage.local.set()` to abort prior to it actually setting the value. `storage.local.set()` is asynchronous, so it starts prior to being aborted, but does not make it far enough to actually change the value in the StorageArea.

Your extension will work if you add `e.preventDefault();` to your `saveOptions()` in *options.js*, which would look like:

```js
function saveOptions(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  browser.storage.local.set({
    color: document.querySelector("#color").value
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your explanation and solution makes perfectly sense, but unfortunately even after adding "e.preventDefault();"  item.color is still undefined. I tested it with new Firefox profiles (where I loaded the it as a temporary Add-on) and several different sites. Am I missing something? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @J.Doe, I can re-test. However, prior to posting this answer, I did test. In both Firefox 50.0.2 and Firefox Developer Edition (52.0a2), I first duplicated the problem — in both, to determine what was causing it — using the code copied directly from your Question. I then tested the solution (in both). With the change above, the color of the border did change to match what was set in the options (once the web page was re-loaded).

Comment: OK. I am now seeing *another* issue which appears related to which Firefox version is being used. I'm still investigating.

Comment: Alright, I just did a new test: I copied the exact same code from my question into new files, downloaded Firefox 50.0.2 from the official site, installed it, went to about:debugging, set the checkbox for "Enable add-on debugging", clicked "Load Temporary Add-on", selected the manifest.json file and opened it. After that I changed the value from blue to red in the settings page of the Add-on but after saving and loading a site the border is still blue.

Comment: When I opened the settings page for the first time after I loaded the Add-on, the color form vanished after one second and the console had the error message: "Content Security Policy: the directive 'frame-src' should not be used any more. Please use the directive 'child-src' instead." with the source (unknown). However going back to the Add-on overview and clicking on preferences again fixed it and the error did not happen again. Maybe this is somehow relevant.

Comment: @J.Doe, I am now getting that (the unchanged blue border) as well in FF50.0.2 (and Beta, FF51.0b6). It works correctly in Dev. Ed. (52.0a2).  The difference is that in 50.0.2 (and 51.0b6) the `storage.local.get()` promise in the content script is returning an Array of 1 Objects (which correctly contains the `color` property) instead of an Object. The same code correctly returns an Object when executed in the *options.js*.

Comment: Nice find, replacing "item.color" with "item[0].color" in the content script makes it work (in 50.0.2). I should have logged only item instead of item.color in the console to find this earlier. However thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: This does appear to be an issue with using `browser.storage.local.get()`.  If you use `chrome.storage.local.get()`, it correctly returns an Object (right alongside the `browser` `get` which incorrectly returns an Array of Objects).

Comment: FYI: I have placed a warning regarding this bug on both the [StorageArea.get()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/get?document_saved=true) page and [Implement a settings page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Implement_a_settings_page?document_saved=true).

Comment: Thanks for the placed warning, that will keep others from running into the same issue as me.